# Вывод разделов catalog.section.list инфоблока news

Tags: php, html, css, битрикс, раздел

Использую шаблон с сайта [W3layouts](https://w3layouts.com/template/publication-a-corporate-blogging-category-website-template/), [Demo](https://demo.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/30-04-2020/publication-liberty-demo_Free/1014263797/web/index.html?_ga=2.171334432.1094583477.1643206889-793075102.1640516188). Сначала встроил слайдер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем создал компонент news для следующих 4-х постов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно у каждого элемента внизу есть список разделов - `Market Tips`, `Sports`, `Techniques`. Есть код для комплексного компонента news

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>

<section class="w3l-blog">
    <div class="text-element-9">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <? $j=0; ?>
<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
    <?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>
    <? $j=$j+1; ?>
    <? if ($j==1) :?>
        <a href="#blog-single.html" class="col-lg-6 blog-article-posts bg-color-one" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
    <? endif; ?>
    <? if ($j==2) :?>
        <a href="#blog-single.html" class="col-lg-6 blog-article-posts bg-color-two" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
    <? endif; ?>
    <? if ($j==3) :?>
        <a href="#blog-single.html" class="col-lg-6 blog-article-posts bg-color-three" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
    <? endif; ?>
    <? if ($j==4) :?>
        <a href="#blog-single.html" class="col-lg-6 blog-article-posts bg-color-four" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
    <? endif; ?>
            <div class="blog-post d-flex flex-wrap align-content-between">
            <div class="post-content">
                <ul class="author-date mb-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <li class="circle-lg avatar"><img src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"] ?>" alt=""></li>
                    <li>by <b><?= $arItem["PROPERTIES"]["AUTHOR"]["VALUE"]?></b></li>
                    <li><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> <?= date('M j, Y', MakeTimestamp($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PUBLICATIONDATE"]["VALUE"]));?></li>
                </ul>
                <h4 class="blog_post_title mb-4"><?=$arItem["NAME"] ?></h4>
                <p class="sub-para">#Market Tips <sup> 36</sup></p>
                <p class="sub-para">#Sports <sup> 235</sup></p>
                <p class="sub-para">#Techniques <sup> 59</sup></p>
            </div>
            <div class="read-button mt-5">Read story <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
        </div>
    </a>
<?endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Каким образом через битрикс можно вывести имена разделов (`Market Tips`, `Sports`, `Techniques`) в этих 4-х постах? Для справки можно использовать [16# Реализация раздела на комплексном компоненте (news) | Видеокурс: Создание сайта на 1С Битрикс](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQuEFMFxq3g) с 15:00 - 16:00 и с 17:00 - 18:10 (в этом видео приведен вывод **кодов разделов** для элемента, а мне нужны **имена разделов**) и [17# Вывод разделов инфоблока (catalog.section.list) | Видеокурс: Создание сайта на 1С Битрикс](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81YJ3_kf_Aw&list=PL8Kt1m2oRch5M1bA334BRwFybdDe38Byd&index=18)
. Подскажите как вывести имена всех разделов для каждого из элементов.

Я нашел частично используемый код (с 1-ого видео)

```html
if (!empty($arResult['ITEMS'])) {
    $arElementsIds = [];
    foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as  $arItem) {
        if (isset($arItem['ID'])) {
            $arElementsIds[] = $arItem['ID'];
        }
    }

    $dbSections = CIBlockElement::GetElementGroups($arElementsIds);
    $arSections = [];
    while ($el = $dbSections->Fetch()) {
        $arSections[] = $el;
    }
    
foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $itemKey => $arItem) {    

        if (isset($arItem['ID'])) {
            $arElementSectionsCodes = [];
            foreach ($arSections as $section) {
                if ($arItem['ID'] == $section['IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID']) {
                    $arElementSectionsCodes[] = $section['CODE'];
                }
            }

            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTIONS_CODES'] = implode(' ', $arElementSectionsCodes);
        } else {
            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTIONS_CODES'] = '';
        }
    }
```

см. [Гитхаб](https://github.com/anvein/bitrix_course/blob/master/web/local/templates/main/components/bitrix/news.list/PortfolioElementsList/result_modifier.php#L35) (полный код фрагмента)

В блоке

```html
        if (isset($arItem['ID'])) {
            $arElementSectionsCodes = [];
            foreach ($arSections as $section) {
                if ($arItem['ID'] == $section['IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID']) {
                    $arElementSectionsCodes[] = $section['CODE'];
                }
            }

            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTIONS_CODES'] = implode(' ', $arElementSectionsCodes);
        } else {
            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTIONS_CODES'] = '';
        }
    }
```

необходимо последовательно вывести все `SECTION_NAME` одного элемента. Как это сделать (дайте подробный ответ)? (или можно на основании второго видео можно сделать?)

Comment: @ВикторКарев помогите.

Comment: Уважаемая администрация можете удалить этот вопрос. Т.к. есть его замена https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1375817/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-iblock-element-id-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0. Хотя этот новый вопрос - вообще-то говоря другой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно проще

```html
<?php
     $db_groups = CIBlockElement::GetElementGroups($arItem['ID'], true);
    
     while($ar_group = $db_groups->Fetch()) {
        ?>
            <p class="sub-para">#<?=$ar_group['NAME'] ?> </p>
        
        <?php   
}
?>
```

Команда GetElementGroups для каждого $arItem['ID'] возвращает список разделов, а затем в цикле while происходит вывод имен разделов из списка.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?
  $arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$IBLOCK_ID,'ID'=>$arElementSectionsIDs);
  $dbList = CIBlockSection::GetList(array(), $arFilter, true);
  while($arResult = $dbList->GetNext())
  {
    echo $arResult['ID'].' '.$arResult['NAME'].'<br>';
  }
?>
```

В $arElementSectionsIDs должен быть массив идентификаторов разделов

Comment: поясните пожалуйста код (подробно). 1. Как должна быть объявлена переменная **$IBLOCK_ID** до строчки `$arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>$IBLOCK_ID,'ID'=>$arElementSectionsIDs);`, где она используется? 2. Судя по моей задаче (необходимо получить список имен разделов для каждого элемента), то получается, что (исходя из последней строчки приведенного вами блока кода - `echo $arResult['ID'].' '.$arResult['NAME'].'<br>';`)  список `$dblist` содержит список разделов  для одного элемента, а мне нужно для каждого элемента получить такой список. (Приведите подробные комментарии к каждой строчке кода)

Comment: $IBLOCK_ID - это id информационного блока, $dblist - в этой переменной храниться произвольное кол-во разделов. Вы можете получать разделы для каждого элемента, сделав цикл по всем элементам