# Семантика и значение $section['IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID']

Tags: php, массивы, веб-программирование, битрикс

Использую шаблон с сайта [W3layouts](https://w3layouts.com/template/publication-a-corporate-blogging-category-website-template/), см. [демо-вид](https://demo.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/30-04-2020/publication-liberty-demo_Free/1014263797/web/index.html?_ga=2.153811645.449130551.1643297517-793075102.1640516188). В нем выводятся 4 поста с помощью комплексного компонента `news` (поскольку присутствуют разделы постов, то используется именно компонент `news`, а не `news.list`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У каждого элемента внизу есть список разделов - `Market Tips`, `Sports`, `Techniques`. Для того чтобы их вывести нашел видео [16# Реализация раздела на комплексном компоненте (news) | Видеокурс: Создание сайта на 1С Битрикс](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQuEFMFxq3g) с 15:30 - 18:10. В нем использовался код (см. [код с Github](https://github.com/anvein/bitrix_course/blob/master/web/local/templates/main/components/bitrix/news.list/PortfolioElementsList/result_modifier.php#L35))

```php
<?php

if (!empty($arResult['ITEMS'])) {
    $arElementsIds = [];
    foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as  $arItem) {
        if (isset($arItem['ID'])) {
            $arElementsIds[] = $arItem['ID'];
        }
    }

    $dbSections = CIBlockElement::GetElementGroups($arElementsIds);
    $arSections = [];
    while ($el = $dbSections->Fetch()) {
        $arSections[] = $el;
    }


    foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $itemKey => $arItem) {
        // Получение Названия основного раздела
        if (isset($arItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'])) {
            $searchSectId = $arItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'];

            foreach ($arSections as $section) {
                if ($section['ID'] === $searchSectId) {
                    $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTION_NAME'] = $section['NAME'];
                }
            }
        }

        if (!isset($arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTION_NAME'])) {
            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTION_NAME'] = '';
        }

        // Получение кодов разделов для элемента
        if (isset($arItem['ID'])) {
            $arElementSectionsCodes = [];
            foreach ($arSections as $section) {
                if ($arItem['ID'] == $section['IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID']) {
                    $arElementSectionsCodes[] = $section['CODE'];
                }
            }

            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTIONS_CODES'] = implode(' ', $arElementSectionsCodes);
        } else {
            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTIONS_CODES'] = '';
        }
    }
}
```

В 1-ом блоке

```php
$arElementsIds = []; // инициализация массива идентификаторов всех постов
    foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as  $arItem) { // проходим в цикле все посты
        if (isset($arItem['ID'])) { 
            $arElementsIds[] = $arItem['ID'];
        } // если у поста установлен идентификатор, то в массив всех идентификаторов записывается идентификатор текущего поста
    }
```

получаем массив идентификаторов всех элементов (постов) - `$arElementsIds`.

Во 2-ом блоке

```php
$dbSections = CIBlockElement::GetElementGroups($arElementsIds);
$arSections = [];
while ($el = $dbSections->Fetch()) {
    $arSections[] = $el;
}
```

получаем массив разделов всех постов - `$arSections` (с помощью метода `GetElementGroups` получаем массив разделов для массива `$arElementsIds`, т.е. фактически получаем массив разделов для всех постов).

В 3-м блоке происходит следующее

```php
foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $itemKey => $arItem) {// в цикле проходим по каждому посту
// Получение Названия основного раздела
if (isset($arItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID'])) { // если установлен идентификатор основного раздела поста
    $searchSectId = $arItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID']; // то присваиваем этот идентификатор переменной $searchSectId 

    foreach ($arSections as $section) { // в цикле проходим по всем разделам
         if ($section['ID'] === $searchSectId) { // если идентификатор раздела совпадает с идентификатором основного раздела поста 
              $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTION_NAME'] = $section['NAME']; // то присваиваем переменной имя основного раздела
          }
        }
    }

if (!isset($arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTION_NAME'])) {
            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTION_NAME'] = '';
}
```

В 4-м блоке возникли проблемы с пониманием кода (несмотря на то, что он созвучен в некотором смысле с кодом 3-ого блока). Для каждого поста происходит следующее

```
// Получение кодов разделов для элемента
if (isset($arItem['ID'])) {// проверяем установлен ли идентификатор у поста 
      $arElementSectionsCodes = []; //инициализация массива кодов разделов поста
      foreach ($arSections as $section) { // проходим по всем разделам 
         if ($arItem['ID'] == $section['IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID']) {
                $arElementSectionsCodes[] = $section['CODE'];
         } // если идентификатор поста равен идентификатору элемента инфоблока (вот как раз код $section['IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID'] непонятен для восприятия), то в массив кодов разделов поста записывается код раздела
       }

      $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTIONS_CODES'] = implode(' ', $arElementSectionsCodes); // для поста все разделы соединяются в одну строку через пробел 
        } else {
            $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTIONS_CODES'] = '';
        }
    }
```

В отличие от 3-го блока, где обращение к `$arItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID']` означало идентификатор **основного раздела** поста инфоблока, то в 4-м блоке происходит обращение к `$section['IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID']`, что непонятно что означает (с одной стороны нужно выцепить все разделы для текущего поста `arItem`, **но с другой стороны каждый пост может входить в несколько разделов и в один раздел может входить несколько постов**, а потому в отличие от `$arItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID']` (в котором четко определена привязка к основному разделу) конструкция `$section['IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID']` непонятно, что означает. Проясните эту неясность (интуитивно понятно, что для каждого поста должны извлечься только разделы, в которые он входит - но полной ясности это не дает).

Answer (score 0):

Именно потому, что каждый пост может входить в несколько разделов и в один раздел может входить несколько постов, и формируется массив $arSections. Фактически каждый элемент этого массива - это информация о паре [номер поста, номер раздела]. Поэтому в 4-м блоке мы пробегаем по этому массиву и ищем информацию о разделах нужного поста.

Проблема с пониманием, скорее всего возникла из-за того, что в 3-м блоке мы хотим просто найти название раздела, и бежим по всему массиву $arSections, переприсваивая нужное имя каждый раз когда встречаем элемент с совпадающим номером раздела. А таких элементов может быть много.

Чтобы не выполнять лишнюю работу, после первого же нахождения имени раздела, надо было прервать внутренний цикл.

```
    foreach ($arSections as $section) { // в цикле проходим по всем разделам
         if ($section['ID'] === $searchSectId) { // если идентификатор раздела совпадает с идентификатором основного раздела поста 
              $arResult['ITEMS'][$itemKey]['SECTION_NAME'] = $section['NAME']; // то присваиваем переменной имя основного раздела
              break;
          }
        }
    }
```